# Uncaught ReferenceError: xx is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add the textbox value but getting the error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffalo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Blade file showing red error on `onchange="------"`

Code is

```php
<tbody>
    @foreach ($buffalodata as $item )
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item->buffaloID}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="eachmorningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" name="eachmorningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" onchange="totalmilk({{$item->buffaloID}})" value="0"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="eacheveningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" name="eacheveningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" onchange="totalmilk({{$item->buffaloID}})"  value="0"></td>
            <td><input type="text"   id="eachtotalmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}"   name="eachtotalmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" value="00" readonly></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

onchange code

```js
function totalmilk(id){
    var morningmilk = "#eachmorningmilk"+id;
    var eveningmilk = "#eacheveningmilk"+id;
    var totalmilk = "eachtotalmilk"+id;
    eachbmorning = parseInt($(morningmilk).val());
    eachbevening = parseInt($(eveningmilk).val());
    var eachbuffalototalmilk = eachbmorning + eachbevening;

    document.getElementById(totalmilk).value=eachbuffalototalmilk;
```

Ref Image[image]

Comment: What's the content of `$item->buffaloID`? You may need to surround with quotes `'`

Comment: The error on your IDE looks like a misconfiguration of the IDE, not properly handling blade syntax.

Comment: thanks... I m new self leaner.... added ' ' = onchange="totalmilk('{{$item->buffaloID}}')"

Comment: Did it work? So I can make a proper answer

Comment: yes..."totalmilk('{{$item->buffaloID}}')"..... added quotes ' after ( .....Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0):

Given this error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffalo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

I suspect what causing's it, is because `$item->buffaloID` contains the value `Buffalo` thus generating the following code

```html
onchange="totalmilk(Buffalo)"
```

Since `Buffalo` is not defined in your Javascript, Javascript will raise this error.
You can easily fix it by surround the value with quotes

```html
onchange="totalmilk('{{$item->buffaloID}}')"
```

And it will generate the following

```html
onchange="totalmilk('Buffalo')"
```